# Wrap std::get<> in helper method

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, stdtuple

I have a class like this:

```
template<typename ...Els>
class Istr {
    std::tuple<Els...> Vals 
}

class Istr1 : public Istr<std::string> {
     void Do() { std::get<0>(Vals) = "Meh."; }
}
```

Is there a way to define a function template which i can use like this?

```
Tok(0) = "Meh."
Istr i; i.Tok(0) = "Meh."
```

Or, if it's not possible, like this?

```
Tok<0>() = "Meh."
```

In my naive approach i came up with a wrong code:

```
template<typename T>
T Tok(size_t i) { return std::get<i>(Vals); }
```

And the compiler can't actually deduce the type of `T` when I implicitly instantiate the template using it.

Comment: We can't accurately deduce what you want to do, from code that _doesn't do that thing_. Please explain what you want to do, in English.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like Boost.Hana, where you can do `Tok[0_c] = "Meh.";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template<size_t i>
auto Tok() -> decltype( std::get<i>(Vals) ) {
    return std::get<i>(Vals);
}
```

[Live demo](http://rextester.com/UKLO72943)

Comment: Or if your compiler supports C++14: `auto Tok()  { return std::get<i>(Vals); }`

Comment: @ChrisDodd no way, you probably meant `decltype(auto) Tok...`

Comment: Thx Igor, i owe you a beer. Now my question is: There's no way the function call could have the form: "Tok(i)" instead of "Tok<i>()"? I Know that "i" can only be a constexpr and i cannot use it as a variable, and what i'm looking for is just syntactic sugar.

Comment: Short of making it a macro, I don't know of any way to pull off `Tok(i)` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Deduce `TI` thanks to the function argument.
template<typename TTuple, typename TI>
auto my_get(TTuple tuple, TI) 
{
    // `TI` needs to be an `std::integral_constant`.
    return std::get<TI{}>(tuple);
}

// `constexpr` variable template.
// `sz_v<0>` is `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0>{}`.
template<std::size_t TI>
constexpr std::integral_constant<std::size_t, TI> sz_v{};

// Example call.
// Results in `std::get<0>(some_tuple)`.
my_get(some_tuple, sz_v<0>);
```

If you define it as a method, you can call it like this:

```
struct some_struct
{ 
    std::tuple<...> some_tuple; 
};

some_struct s;
s.my_get(sz_v<0>);
```